# How to compress pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Below I am showing few entries of my dataframe. My (each) dataframe has millions row.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'stamp':'12/31/2020 9:35:42 AM', 'value': 21.99, 'trigger': True}, 
        {'stamp':'12/31/2020 10:35:42 AM', 'value': 22.443, 'trigger': False}, 
        {'stamp':'12/31/2020 11:35:42 AM', 'value': 19.00, 'trigger': False}, 
        {'stamp':'12/31/2020 9:45:42 AM', 'value': 45.02, 'trigger': False}, 
        {'stamp':'12/31/2020 9:55:42 AM', 'value': 48, 'trigger': False}, 
        {'stamp':'12/31/2020 11:35:42 AM', 'value': 48.99, 'trigger': False}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Below is how few ways I can save:

```
df.to_parquet('df.parquet', compression = 'gzip')

df.to_csv('df.csv')
```

I don't see much improvement in to_parquet as compared to to_csv. I wish to minimize the file size on hard drive. is there any way out?

Answer (score 1):

parquet gives you compression over a column when that columns (e.g.) has many continuous sequences of the same value. (See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Parquet#Compression_and_encoding) for more) From your example data only `trigger` shows a sign of that, but the improvement may not be large because it was not the one taking up most space in the first place.

Saving integer is cheaper than saving a long string, so you may consider to change your `stamp` from `str` into timestamp value which is `int`, by doing this

```
df['stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['stamp']).values.astype(np.int64) // 10**9
```

We divide it by `10**9` because your `stamp` appears to be precise to the level of second only, instead of nanosecond which is the default.

but you will need to convert it back to the readable `str` form the next time you read the saved data, by

```
df['stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['stamp'] * 10**9)
```

Comment: perhaps sort your dataframe by `stamp` so that same `stamps` are adjacent to one another, to exploit the benefit from a parquet? btw, what're the size in KB of your parquet with `string` `stamp`, and the size in KB of your parquet with `int` `stamp`?

Comment: i am just wondering how many % is the reduction by converting string to integer.

Comment: I think #1 sorting `stamp` + parquet; #2 convert string stamp into int; #3 save 2 files, one with only `Trigger=True`, and one with only `Trigger=False`, then you can drop the Trigger column at all from both files.